# svg image not showing

Tags: html, svg

This is the code below am I not seeing something to get it up and running?

```
<svg base="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="550" y="475" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
   <image xlink:href="app3.JPG" x="100" y="75" width="300" height="167" id="image1" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: Can you set this up on JSFiddle or something, so we can see what might be the problem?

Comment: Does the image [http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/app3.JPG](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/app3.JPG) exist? I get a 404 error when trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such attribute as base you want xmlns instead there. You've no defined xlink namespace either.

If you're embedding SVG in html you should specify a width and height for the `<svg>` element too. 100% is probably what you want.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="550" y="475" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
   <image xlink:href="app3.JPG" x="100" y="75" width="300" height="167" id="image1" />
 </svg>
```

You may also need to specify a width/height for the div as a style.

Comment: Okay made changes, image is still not showing. I put a html image with the same attributes and it works. Here is the change               <div id="container">
   <svg x="550" y="475" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
<image xlink:href="app3.JPG" x="100" y="75" width="300" height="167" id="image1" style="border: 3px solid black;"/>
</svg>
</div>